# Help understanding the mathematical definition of states in Quantum Mechanics

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, quantum-mechanics

I've been looking into the fundamentals of quantum mechanics recently. In regular undergrad text one usually finds the definition that a state is an element in some Hilbert space $H$ and an observable is a bounded self-adjoint linear map from $H$ to the complex numbers.

A more accurate definition (although more involved mathematically), that actually manages to include mixed states (which the previous definition doesn't), is that observables are bounded self-adjoint elements of the algebra $A$ of linear maps from $H$ to the complex numbers, while states are defined as positive definite, normalized, linear maps from $A$ to the complex numbers.

What is surprising to me is that with this definition, $S$ (the set of all states) includes not only the elements of $H$ (via an isomorphism), but also some extra states (which is easily seen with particular examples). The confusing part is that from these definitions it seems to me that $S$ is a subset of $(H^*)^*$, which should be isomorphic to a subset in $H$ (or at lest so I know from my linear algebra courses); however, the matter is reversed: $H$ is isomorphic to a subset of $S$. What am I missing here?

Comment: The "undergraduate" definition of a state that you refer to is a [pure state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_state#Pure_states), which in the mathematical formalism is a (non-zero) element of $H$ that is normalized to have norm $1$. A [mixed state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_state#Mixed_states), on the other hand, is a (non-zero) positive operator over $H$ that is normalized to have trace $1$. It is **incorrect** to say that the mixed states form a subset of $H^{**}$.

Comment: Also, for general topological vector spaces, $H$ is isomorphic to a subset of $H^{**}$, not the other way around (as you have indicated). Also, because $H$ is a Hilbert space, we have $H^{*} \cong H$, and hence $H^{**} \cong H$.